# How to restart postgresql on OS X?

Tags: macos, postgresql

Can't find how to restart postgresql on OS X using command line in order to apply changes in pg_hba.conf. I'v tried various command from web and docs. How to do it right?

EDIT:Response of attempt to find the path looks this way:

```
TheKotik       73454   0.0  0.0  2619360    804   ??  S     7:20PM   0:01.57 /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin/postgres -D /Users/TheKotik/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.6 -p 5432
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log restart
```

`/usr/local/var/postgres` is the location of the database storage area, and `/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log` is my log file for postgres. The last word `restart` is the operative word here. You can also use `start` to start the service.

You can find the location of the database storage area by running `ps aux | grep postgres | grep -- -D`

Comment: pg_ctl: directory "/usr/local/var/postgres" does not exist

Comment: Updated my post

Comment: Ah I just saw your edit. Try this: `pg_ctl -D /Users/TheKotik/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.6 -l /Users/TheKotik/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.6/server.log restart`

Comment: response is :      
pg_ctl: unrecognized operation mode "Support/Postgres/var-9.6"

Comment: Surround the arguments in quotes: `pg_ctl -D "/Users/TheKotik/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.6" -l "/Users/TheKotik/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var-9.6/server.log" restart`

Comment: pg_ctl: could not open PID file "/Library/PostgreSQL/9.6/data/postmaster.pid": Permission denied

Answer (score 83):

Just in case postgres has been installed using homebrew, you can also run below command:

```
brew services restart postgres
```

Comment: Error: Formula `postgresql` is not installed.

Comment: Use `brew services list` to get the right service name. Then use `brew services restart <service name>`. Example `brew services restart postgresql@12`

Comment: For me it was, 'brew services restart postgresql@14'. Use the package name when you installed it using brew.

Answer (score 16):

for `hba.conf` changes to apply you don't need to restart - just reload.

run `select pg_reload_conf()` in psql

also:

run `show data_directory` in psql to find your data dir...

Comment: select pg_reload_conf() has no effect

Comment: then you probably edit wrong hba file... in posql run `show hba_file` to check

Comment: thanks a lot..I was restarting machine after adding entry in `pg_hba.conf`...saved lots of time...thanks a lot.

Comment: sure thing. my pleasure

Comment: `select pg_reload_conf()` might have no effect because you need to add a `;` after it to run the command.

Answer (score 9):

For PostgreSQL 13.4 running on macOS Catalina 10.15.7, I had a different location for my data file and thus a different command.

```
sudo -u postgres /Library/PostgreSQL/13/bin/pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/13/data restart
```

Not sure why my data dir is different than others but it worked.  I also had to find my postgresql.conf file in that folder using

```
sudo ls -l /Library/PostgreSQL/13/data/
```

Answer (score 4):

Adapted from above answers and comments:

Find which version of postgres brew is running using:

```bash
brew services list
```

then run restart by appending the version:

```bash
brew services restart postgresql@15
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ensure you are restarting your correct Postgres version (e.g. version 15) AND your Postgres is not installed as a Service, then you can use the pg_ctl command and specify your data directory. Where is your data directory? Do the following:

```
% psql
viglione=# SELECT name, setting, context FROM pg_settings WHERE category = 'File Locations';
       name        |                     setting                     |  context   
-------------------+-------------------------------------------------+------------
 config_file       | /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@15/postgresql.conf | postmaster
 data_directory    | /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@15                 | postmaster
 external_pid_file |                                                 | postmaster
 hba_file          | /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@15/pg_hba.conf     | postmaster
 ident_file        | /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@15/pg_ident.conf   | postmaster
(5 rows)
```

I like to project the context column to reaffirm the settings that do require restart. If the value is postmaster, then you must use `pg_ctl restart` and not `pg_ctl reload`. Note the data_directory in row two. We can then specify that as an option to pg_ctl restart. First exit psql and then run the command at the OS level (note since in my case I am using homebrew package manager, i wouldn't use this option):

```
viglione# \q
% pg_ctl restart -D  /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@15
```

Given I am using homebrew, which is a system service, I would use this option:

```
% brew services restart postgresql@15
```

Answer (score 2):

Switch over to the postgres account on your machine by running the following command:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
```

Then restart with:`/Library/PostgreSQL/{version}/bin/pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/{version}/data restart`

Answer (score 1):

For mac

```
sudo -u postgres /Library/PostgreSQL/15/bin/pg_ctl -D /Library/PostgreSQL/15/data restart
```

Worked for me.